# Controlling Arduino from web?

Tags: arduino, web-interface

I am making a project in which I have several servo motors and LED's connected to the Arduino Mega 2560. I want to control these from a web interface over wifi. I have a Raspberry Pi which can act as the intermediate. But I am not able to figure out the correct way to do so. Is it even possible? if yes, then how?

Thanks, I would be very obliged.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You will need to learn programming skills.  You don't actually need the Arduino.  You can control servos and LEDs from the Pi.  Have a look through http://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/ to see if you can find a similar project.

Comment: Actually there are too many servos, therefore I believe that using arduino is the best option. Moreover, can I control arduino from a java servlet active on raspberry pi and give commands to servlet from the web? Is this possible? As I have no problem with programming skills, but I have got low experience with PI and Arduino.

Comment: Here is a similar question:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63521/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-control-a-number-of-pi3-from-a-website